# Unable to boot Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot

I'm new to this, but here goes:

I have a Sony Vaio laptop that I wanted to run only Ubuntu, so I removed Windows 8 and used a bootable USB stick to start and install Ubuntu. After doing so, I can't boot Ubuntu (or anything), other than from the USB-stick. I was told to paste the following link that I got from using the Boot-Repair tool: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8676303/

Any help on how I can get this computer to boot would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:**
This is what I see when I try to boot my computer:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxyshf5J82QSRG1oRFhHT0RxWEk/view?usp=sharing

if I then go to "Start VAIO Care (Rescue Mode)", I get the option to boot from my USB-stick.

From here, I can boot the computer from the USB-stick. But I still cannot get into my Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Up to what step you can see? Can you see the grub menu?

Comment: If the grub menu is the menu where I can chose to install or boot from USB-stick, then I can get to it, but _only_ if I'm chosing to boot from usb-stick when my computer loads. I'll add a picture to my question.

Comment: No no no, I thought you have already installed Ubuntu on the hard disk. If you have not installed yet, then at first you have(should) to boot from the USB stick and you will be provided with two options, try Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu. choose Install Ubuntu and select the same partition where Windows was installed(**Since you don't want Windows on your system at all**) and you have to format before installing.

Comment: Oh, I just spent 10 minutes trying to upload images without 10 rep. Yeah, problem is that I have installed Ubuntu. I just can't boot it.

Comment: I presume it is the image of your laptop's recovery option and not of either Windows boot manager or the grub. And it is good to try troubleshooting(recovery) first.

Answer (score 0):

Before you proceed, If you don't want any headache at the beginning it self just go to last two lines of my answer.

Well since you have confirmed that you have installed Ubuntu there are two possibilities.
In the question you have mentioned **I can't boot Ubuntu (or anything), other than from the USB-stick**

1. May be your boot order in BIOS is set to boot from USB device first.

Solution: Simply remove your USB device and try to reboot, if not worked, use bios key to inter BIOS and change boot order. If that doesn't work,

This may not be a perfect answer but its worth to give it a try.

2. Since [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8676303/) it says **=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.**, may be you have to reinstall Grub boot loader to MBR(Master Boot Record). The reason I'm suggesting this solution is because [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1715216) post states similar problem. Follow the steps below. But before installing grub boot loader try toggling the boot flag from Method:1 if the /dev/sda is not bootable.

This method needs command prompt but it has not mentioned how to go to command prompt when the OS is itself not able to load. Hence I assume you have to press letter "c" when grub menu appears. Reboot and when grub menu appears, press c to open command line. Then enter,

[Source](http://ask.xmodulo.com/install-grub-bootloader-master-boot-record-ubuntu-mint.html) for this method

**Method 1:**

It's assumed that /dev/sda is the disk which contains a boot partition.
First, using fdisk command, verify that the boot partition (typically the first partition) in /dev/sda is tagged as "bootable". If the partition is bootable, it should show "*" under "Boot" column(with * symbol) in the fdisk output.

> fdisk /dev/sda

press P to list the partitions after it shows

> Command (m for help): p

If the boot partition is not bootable, mark it as "bootable". You can press "a" on fdisk to toggle a bootable flag. After changing a bootable flag, make sure to press "w" to write the change to disk.

Then use the Method 2 to install the GRUB bootloader.

[Source](http://wiredrevolution.com/system-administration/install-the-grub-boot-loader-to-the-mbr) for this method.

**Method 2:** Note: Since you are new to Ubuntu, keep this in mind. In the below commands # symbol, > symbol and the text before > symbol should be shown in your command line, and not to be typed as a command.

eg: In the below command, **# grub-install /dev/sda**, you have to type only **grub-install /dev/sda**.

> # grub-install /dev/sda

It has said in the source that this is an automatic re-installation method. If that fails, start by launching the grub command shell manually.

> # grub

If your not sure of the device to specify for the installation, you can ask GRUB to tell you. Run this command and GRUB will attempt to find your GRUB installation on all available device partitions on the system. If found GRUB will output all the partitions containing GRUB installations in GRUB naming format. You can select the correct device and use in the next step.

> grub> find /boot/grub/menu.lst

The output will be something like

> (hd0,0)

Set your root partition which contains the boot directory as well as the GRUB installation.

> grub> root (hd0,0)

Install GRUB to the MBR of your first hard drive device.

> grub> setup (hd0)

Exit Grub.

> grub> quit

Reboot, you should hopefully see the menu on start up.

> # reboot

Hope this helps.

**If everything else failed just reinstall the whole Ubuntu OS and make sure you format(Windows installed partition) before you install Ubuntu on it.**